# iOS 5 Safari cache bug

Tags: safari, ios5

as you may be noticed, the iOS Safari loads from cache regardless the cache settings in http header.

Is there a workaround to force a reload of all resources ? Its pretty bad due the development of a site.

Thanks a lot,

here is the apple user discussion https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3385843?start=0&tstart=0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have control over the site you're trying to load?

If so, check this out:

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472881/So-You-Dont-Want-To-Cache-Huh.htm

Oh, one more thing... you've asked a dozen questions on StackOverflow so far and have accepted *none* of them. I only answered your question because it took me 60 seconds to look up an answer, but if you want other users to feel more motivated to answer your questions, please mark answers as "accepted".